# What is the solution to the riddle of Yorn?

Tags: broken-age

I've tried every item, tried talking to everyone, even everyone in Meriloft, but I'm getting no closer to solving the riddle. None of the items I have seem to be the answer, am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a fruit! Which you can get

> from the tree in Meriloft: [image]
>  To get a fruit, go to the left side of the tree and grab the low hanging branch. A fruit will fall off. Stand near the trunk to drop to the tree's roots, then move to the left to find the fruit waiting in a bird's nest.

Comment: I thought it was peach...

Comment: @JohnoBoy Actually, I'm not sure it was referred to as any particular fruit, just a 'fruit'.

Comment: I think that if you specify where to get the fruit you should specify the method as well, feel free to revert my edit if you think it's unnecessary...

Answer (score 0):

its the peach in the tree up at Meriloft! Get back to the house and climb your way up to Meriloft, then you go to the tree shake it down then you shall grab it from the nest below and make your way back up and go back to the guards with the peach as your answer! Unless you still have it that is.